# Changing the top-margin on one image is shifting all images within the same container

Tags: html, css

I have a few Links/images sitting side by side in a container. 
The container has its overflow property set to `overflow: hidden` and the images are 'sunken' into the container using `margin-top: -50px;`.

When the user hovers over the link I want the image to slide down out of the container and when the user hovers out the image jumps back up.

[Here is a demo of what I have currently.](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/zjWaz/8/)

Here is my css ( I will post it all in case there are problems somewhere else that is causing this)

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#w {
    display:table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#iw {
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width: 100%;
}
#iiw {
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    height: 125px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#iiw a {
     margin-left: 8px;
     margin-right: 8px;   
}
#iiw a img {
    margin-top: -50px;
    height: 100px;
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0.8em 1em #444;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0.8em 1em #444;
    -o-box-shadow:0 0.8em 1em #444;
    box-shadow:0 0.8em 1em #444;
    -moz-border-radius:0 0 10px 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius:0 0 10px 20px;
    -o-border-radius:0 0 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 20px;

}
```

and html HTML markup is

```
<div id="w">
    <div id="iw">
        <div id="iiw">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://stackoverflow.com/content/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png" />
            </a>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://programmers.stackexchange.com/content/programmers/img/apple-touch-icon.png" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using JQuery right now to do the hover events (for ease of use), however the final product will have no JQuery (***so don't comment on the JQuery code***)

---

**Edit** I realize I left that code out.. oops. 
very simple stuff. just using it to swap the `margin-top` property

```
$("a").hover(function() {
    $(this).children().css("margin-top", "-2px");
}, function() {
    $(this).children().css("margin-top", "-50px");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#iiw a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

Them `a` tags need to be block level.

Comment: How do I keep that centre aligned? It seems i'm adding FAR too much css to support this centre alignment *assuming I have to add a fair bit more to support the left float*

Comment: You would set #iw to have `text-align: center;` and #iiw to `display:inline-block;` OR give #iiw a fixed width and `margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: Here is a jfiddle. I rewrote some of your HTML as well. http://jsfiddle.net/zjWaz/20/

Answer (score 0):

It appears that elements that share the same line will align themselves with the lowest element in that line. When you set the top margin of an image to be much lower than the rest, the other images will drop down so their bottom edges align with it.

To avoid this behavior, try adding `vertical-align:top;` to your #iiw a img block. I've applied the change to your example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zjWaz/22/).